# Loading data from JSON file to html/ console

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest

Inside the body tag of this html file, I have a button that clicking it should result in getting contents of colors.json into console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="primary" src="colors.json"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
     function load() {
      var someData_notJSON = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(someData_notJSON[0].red);
      }

      function loadJSON(callback) {

        var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        xobj.open('GET', 'colors.json', true); 
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {                  
              callback(xobj.responseText);
            }
    };
    xobj.send(null); //line 24
  }

  function init() {
    loadJSON(function(response) {
      var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(actual_JSON);

    });
  }    

    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick=" init()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the colors.json file:

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
          "color": "black",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
            "hex": "#000"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "white",
          "category": "value",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
            "hex": "#FFF"
          }
        },
    ]
}
```

On page load I get this error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**
Do you know what causes this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have an unnecessary comma at the end of your array:

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
          "color": "black",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
            "hex": "#000"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "white",
          "category": "value",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
            "hex": "#FFF"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have already tested removing that last comma, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
          "color": "black",
          "category": "hue",
          "type": "primary",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
            "hex": "#000"
          }
        },
        {
          "color": "white",
          "category": "value",
          "code": {
            "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
            "hex": "#FFF"
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can you remove the last comma and try it out.

Comment: I have already tested removing that last comma, but it did not help.

Comment: try to add "type": "primary" in second list and check